# Regular expression for testing for personal emails it

Tags: jquery, regex

Her is my code:

`var gmail_pattern = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\.{1}])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\@gmail(\.[a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i);`

But if I test `gmail_pattern.test(email)` it does not work when the email field has Gmail address.

Comment: Check this: https://regex101.com/r/7zEWL3/1

Comment: eh, works for me ^

Answer (score -1):

[Online Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/) is a good tool to test your regexes. Otherwise you can find a decent regex for email [here](http://emailregex.com/), that page also has a link to [a page describing why there is no regex that matches all email adresses.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)